# Difference betweeen laptops and mobiles in non responsive web design

Tags: android, html, css

For any non-responsive web design, let's say http://www.soe.gr  I've noticed the following behavior: When decreasing the resolution in a laptop e.g. to 800x600 or smaller an horizontal scrollbar appears. However, for the same resolution a mobile phone fits the design to the existent space without any horizontal scrollbar. The same happens for smaller resolutions. The site just becomes smaller and smaller and no horizontal scrollbar appears. Why this difference? Is there any explanation for that? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Android's case, it depends on the `WebSettings` of the `WebView` containing the site.

What's probably causing the behavior is the Layout Algorithm - see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLayoutAlgorithm%28android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm%29).
If you call `yourWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);`, the site should render as if it were on a desktop or laptop machine.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers will have the notion of Viewport which will do a couple of things:

1. If no viewport on the page - then assume the site is a desktop site and give a wide viewport of 900px for example. (there may some smart things browsers will do to detect desired width based on elements with a min-width etc). The browser will then 'zoom' out so you can see all the viewport
2. If there is a viewport then the mobile browser set's width based on this (device-width will make the viewport the same as the devices width in CSS pixels OR if it's a pixel value then it acts the same as desktop but the developer can define the 900px value)

On desktop, the viewport doesn't affect anything on desktop, so you'll get the horizontal scrolling based on the width of the content. If it's a fluid layout then obviously the width of the screen will affect the UI, but that's it.